# String.Replace doesn't replace all matches

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, replace

Why does `line2` replaces only alternating half of occurrences?

```
    Dim line1 As String = "AAA|BBB|CCC|CCC|CCC|CCC|EEE|FFF"
    Dim line2 As String = "AAA|BBB|CCC|CCC|CCC|CCC|EEE|FFF"
    Dim line3 As String = "AAA|BBB|CCC|CCC|CCC|CCC|EEE|FFF"

    line1 = line1.Replace("CCC", "")
    line2 = line2.Replace("|CCC|", "||")
    line3 = line3.Replace("CCC|", "|")
```

Result:

```
line1 = "AAA|BBB|||||EEE|FFF" -- OK, but fails when element is "..|ZZZCCCZZZ|.."
line2 = "AAA|BBB||CCC||CCC|EEE|FFF" -- Not OK
line3 = "AAA|BBB|||||EEE|FFF" -- OK, but fails similar to Line1 edge-case for "..|ZZZCCC|.."
```

I have tried using RegEx, but get similar results.

Is there really no better way than this, below?

```
Do While line1.Contains("|CCC|")
    line1 = line1.Replace("|CCC|", "||")
Loop
```

Comment: Once it finds the first token, it starts looking for the _next_ one _after_ that token. So it finds `|CCC|`, replaces it, then continues on and the first thing it sees is `CCC|` which doesn't match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once it finds the first token, it starts looking for the *next* one *after* that token. So it finds `|CCC|`, replaces it, then continues on and the first thing it sees is `CCC|` which doesn't match. It doesn't pre-scan the string looking for tokens to replace.

Consider it like this:

Given `AAA|BBB|CCC|CCC|CCC|CCC|EEE|FFF`

It runs to `AAA|BBB|CCC|` ***HOLD IT*** `|CCC|` was found, let's start building our string:

`AAA|BBB` + `||` (our replacement)

Now let's move on, we now have `CCC|CCC|CCC|EEE|FFF` left to work with.

It runs to `CCC|CCC|` ***HOLD IT*** `|CCC|` was found, let's continue adding to our string:

`AAA|BBB||CCC` + `||` (our replacement)

Now let's move on, we now have `CCC|CCC|EEE|FFF` and so on and so on.

EDIT: Considering the entry on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) describing the return value:

> A string that is equivalent to the current string except that all
>   instances of oldValue are replaced with newValue.

One *could* read that as what you expect that it pre-scans the string and finds *all* matches. I don't see anything in the MSDN doc that describes this corner case. Perhaps this is something that should be added to the MSDN doc.

Comment: I can understand why this is confusing though because it doesn't modify the original string.  This almost seems like an implementation detail, however a very logical one.  Shame this isn't mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: @JasonSperske It doesn't seem confusing .. at least not after using such a method once or twice :D The match *consumes everything it matches* and *skips over* any replaced text. If this were not the case then there could be infinite replacement recursion! e.g. `line1.Replace("X", "X")`

Comment: @pst - that seems like a logical optimization, although it could also be done by counting the number of times the `while found, replace` is executed with an escape limit based on the length of original string, pattern and replacement.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily an issue with infinite recursion; I don't see it _re_-evaluating the string. I _could_ see it scan once, find indices to replace, do a bit of math/shifting probably, then run through once replacing them all even when tokens are shared. Just this would take longer (two passes) and behave differently than most string "replace" methods in programming (AFAIK the .NET implementation is based on the "standard" way). If you want to roll your own replacement that does this, you're certainly welcome to (and extension methods encourage you to!)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair How would `"XX".Replace("X", "XX")` be evaluated if the match and replacement were not both skipped? (I've changed the data slightly from above to increase the complexity/ambiguity. Note that Leon's answer contains a max-iteration limit with a specific rule.)

Comment: @pst First scan would pick up that indices `0` and `1` should be replaced with `"XX"`. Then traverses through the string a second time, hits index `0` and uses `"XX"` instead, continues traversing the string, hits index `1` and uses `"XX"` instead. Once traversal is finish, it's left with `"XXXX"`. I'm suggesting doing it in two passes, not recursive passes.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Oh, I see what you're getting at (that the test-case does a poor job of showing). If I wanted that behavior (to not consume all the matched string), I would just to use a look-around regular expression.

Comment: @pst No, consider instead your string: `"FFF|CCC|CCC|".Replace("|CCC|", "||")`. First pass identifies indices `{3, 7}`. Then copies the string up to index `3`: `"FFF"`, inserts replacement `"||"` (resulting in `"FFF||"`). Might need to do checks to see if there's overlap or gaps between hits in general (based on the difference between indices). So in this case, it picks up on the overlap and inserts another `||`. The logic itself might be a bit fuzzy, I'm sure I could hammer out a general case that's relatively fast with minimal string reconstruction but don't have the time at the moment. :)

Comment: Sorry, I see the confusion with the `"XX".Replace("X", "XX")`; that's a special case anyway where they're pretty much equivalent (and my description wasn't any better!). The difference is more apparent when the search pattern is longer than 1 character and there's more variety in the source string.

Comment: Yeah, I chose wrong test-data; I was thinking of something else. For an alternative approach that allows "not eating" all the match, I was thinking of something like `Regex.Replace("FFF|CCC|CCC|", "(?<=[|])CCC(?=[|])", "")` (albeit it requires a regular expression and modification of the replacement data).

Comment: @pst I don't think that works for all cases. I would expect `"FFF|CCC|CCC||CCC|"` to result in 6 `|` pipes (or `"FFF||||||"`) but that regex results in only 5 ("`FFF|||||`")

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'd argue for the "correctness" of the latter *here* - but this is partly because that's what *I* envision/expect the goal of the original poster is. (I very well might be wrong in this case, and have no doubt that there are counter-examples.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using regular expressions or `string.Replace` you could parse the values, filter the ones you don't want and join them back together.

```
line1 = string.Join("|", line1.Split("|").Select(s => s == "CCC" ? "" : s).ToArray());
```

Sorry I don't know the VB equivalent.

Comment: Question only because I'm curious :-)
Won't this be a memory consuming operation? I mean...string operations are basically memory consuming.

Comment: @MatsMagnem Well it definitely creates an array of strings and then the new joined string, but all of that will be up for garbage collection.  But yeah, this could hit an out of memory error for an extremely large string.  In that case you'd want a buffer type of algorithm, but I figured in this case the strings wouldn't be that large.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future, I've added an extension method to overcome this limitation in the framework:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function ReplaceAll(ByVal original As String, ByVal oldValue As String, ByVal newValue As String) As String

    If newValue.Contains(oldValue) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("New value can't be a subset of OldValue as infinite replacements can occur.", newValue)
    End If

    Dim maxIterations As Integer = original.Length \ oldValue.Length

    While maxIterations > 0 AndAlso original.Contains(oldValue)
        original = original.Replace(oldValue, newValue)
        maxIterations -= 1
    End While

    Return original

End Function
```

Comment: I'd argue this is not "limitation" .. but if this is what you need .. however, *I suspect this will fail (or "act unexpectedly") in certain cases*. In particular, it is possible that max iterations runs out too early before all the original replacements are performed.

Comment: (And this will lead to precisely the infinite-recursion case I was talking about in my previous comments if the match can match the replacement.)

Comment: If new value contains old value inside it `.Replace("X","XX")` exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I might use a [regular expression replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) with a [*look-around*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) for this case.

Consider this example:

```cs
Regex.Replace("FCCCF|CCC|CCC|", "((?<=[|])CCC(?=[|]))", "")
// ->
"FCCCF|||"
```

This will always match the correct number of times and is not prone to any infinite recursion issues. It requires modification to an appropriate regular expression and altering the replacement data.

However, note per Chris's comment:

```cs
Regex.Replace("FCCCF|CCC|CCC||CCC|", "((?<=[|])CCC(?=[|]))", "")
// -> only 5 pipes: verify this is correct per the intended semantics
"FCCCF|||||"
```

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, with that regex `FCCCF|CCC|CCC||CCC|` results in `FCCCF|||||` when I would expect `FCCCF||||||` (5 vs 6 pipes). EDIT: Perhaps at this point we're moving from the realm of "base class library" and into "business rules" anyway :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks for pointing that out - it's the little unexpected details that can bite really hard.